# Discord.py I need help to create a Channel to count the bots on Server

Tags: python, count, discord

I've created a channel that displays the number of members on the server, but I couldn't create a channel that displays the number of bots on the server, could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The discordpy API docs would suggest that `User` and `Member` objects have a `bot` attribute that can help you determine the correct count.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.bot